# Url without trailing slash needs to redirect to URL with trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site. The URL example.com/he/ loads the correct page but example.com/he shows a Page Not Found Error.
What do I need to add to the .htaccess file to make example.com/he redirect to example.com/he/?
I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you want to add trailing `/` to only `/he` URI or to all the URIs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If always the same directory you can just add this line to your htaccess in order to redirect URL without trailing slash to URL with trailing slash.

```
RewriteRule ^he$ /he/ [L,R=301]
```

If you have other directories you may declare each one after another.